# Format date in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a date object coming from my java backend and I need to format it using angular or JS (I cannot use any plugin).

My issue is that my java backend only accepts a string and parses it to date object later.

In my current angular code, I am using:

```
JSON.parse(oldTime);
```

To convert the object to a string

My current output:

```
2015-08-12T05:00:00.000Z
```

Output I need:

```
2015-08-12 02:00:00
```

Comment: `05:00:00` gets changed to `02:00:00` ?

Comment: regex (was a removed tag) is useless here. Use the Javascript Date object to format the date and normalize it according to timezones.

Comment: @vks not sure where 05 came from in my current output may have to do with timezone but 02 was a random hour I entered

Comment: You definitely should look at the data filter here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the date filter when outputting the date value in your view

So your HTML includes the variable and the filter

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>{{time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
</div>
```

and in your javascript file you create the date object from the string literal. This will format the date in the browsers local time.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var jsonvalue = '2015-08-12T05:00:00.000Z';
    $scope.time = new Date(jsonvalue);
    $scope.parsed = $filter('date')($scope.time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
});
```

Notice that you can use the filter module in your controller to parse dates there as well. In the example above the `parsed` variable will now hold the correct format of your date, as a string.

A fiddle is available; http://jsfiddle.net/9pd7rbur/2/

Comment: I need the date to be formatted for the url not just the view